# Bass Library Error: Device(Illegal Device Number)

Tags: .net, audio, audio-recording, bass, bass.dll

I have this method that records audio in C#:

```
public Task StartNewRecording()
{
    _name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    _name += " - " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()[..4];
    _name += ".wav";
    var path = Path.Combine(_mainPath, _name);
    _writer = new WaveFileWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read),
        new WaveFormat());

    Bass.RecordInit();
    _recordingHandle = Bass.RecordStart(44100, 2, BassFlags.RecordPause, RecordingCallback);
    Bass.ChannelPlay(_recordingHandle, true);
    _startTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The recording works in development mode but when I publish it for MacOS and Windows/Microsoft, their is problem while recording. To be specific, on the MacOS, I am receiving the error Device which means **illegal device number**.
The error is being thrown on the line 11. You can see the code `Bass.RecordInit();`. This function returns a false value. If it is a false value, it means there was an error and while trying to check the error by adjusting that part of the code like the below:

```
var isSuccess = Bass.RecordInit();
if (!isSuccess)
{
    throw new Exception(Bass.LastError.ToString());
}
```

This code is throwing the **device** error after being published for MacOS. I am confused because, it works perfectly fine on development mode and after publishing, the error suddenly appears.

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance!

i run the function `Bass.RecordInit()` but it is returning false and upon checking the error it was a **device **error. I expect the function to return true on publish mode and get rid of the error.